# Disable SSL in XMPPpy?

Tags: python, ssl

I need to Disable SSL Connection  while connecting to gmail, I had try this code :

```
import xmpp

username = 'username'
passwd = 'password'
to='friend@gmail.com'
msg='hello :)'

client = xmpp.Client('gmail.com')
client.connect(('talk.google.com',5223),None,"None",None)
client.auth(username, passwd, 'omar')
client.sendInitPresence()
message = xmpp.Message(to, msg)
message.setAttr('type', 'chat')
client.send(message)
```

"None" most be ssl=None without (") but it's not working , Any Help ?

Comment: the ssl connection still working :(

Comment: and some times when i change it to facebook it gives this error : 
client.py" line 209, in auth while not self.dispatcher.stream._document_attrs and self.process(1): pass ttributeerror: client instance has no attribute 'dispatcher'

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://xmpppy.sourceforge.net/apidocs/xmpp.client.Client-class.html#connect) :

- If you want ssl/tls support to be discovered and enable automatically - leave third argument as None. (ssl will be autodetected only if port is 5223 or 443)
- If you want to force SSL start (i.e. if port 5223 or 443 is remapped to some non-standard port) then set it to 1.
- If you want to disable tls/ssl support completely, set it to 0.

Comment: please give the code i realy read that but i didn't get it :(

Comment: I guess it should look like `client.connect(('talk.google.com', 5223), None, 0, None)` (I can't test the code)